# Размер отрисовки OpenGL слишком большой

Tags: java, opengl, opengles, lwjgl

Пытаюсь вывести **квадрат** размера **1x1** на экран в OpenGL, он должен рендериться на весь экран, так как координаты OpenGL **1x1**, но он почему- то выводится далеко за пределы окна, вот пример квадрата **0.3x0.3**:

```
public class Renderer {

    private final int vaoRectangle;
    private final int rectangleProgram;
    private final int rectangleBuffer;


    Vector3f cameraPosition = new Vector3f(0, 0, 1f);


    Renderer() throws Exception {
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glClearColor(0.04f, 1.0f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
        glPointSize(50);//размер точки


        String rectangleVertexSource = IOUtils.toString(getClass().getResourceAsStream("shaders/rectangle.vert"));
        String rectangleFragmentSource = IOUtils.toString(getClass().getResourceAsStream("shaders/rectangle.frag"));
        rectangleProgram = Util.createShaderProgram(rectangleVertexSource, rectangleFragmentSource);

        //заполняется в момент рендеринга

        vaoRectangle = glGenVertexArrays();//вао под прямоугольник
        glBindVertexArray(vaoRectangle);
        rectangleBuffer = glGenBuffers();//квадрат заполняется в момент рендеринга
    }


    private void drawLine(int i) {
        glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(rectangleProgram, "c"), 0, 0, 1);//верхняя
        glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, i, 2);
    }

    //рисование прямоугольника
    private void renderRectangle() {
        //матрица view 
        FloatBuffer vMatrix = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
        new Matrix4f()
                .lookAt(cameraPosition.x, cameraPosition.y, cameraPosition.z,
                        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                        0.0f, 1f, 0.0f).get(vMatrix);
        //матрица проекции
        Matrix4f p = new Matrix4f().perspective((float) Math.toRadians(45.0f), 480f / 480f, 0.01f, 100.0f);
        FloatBuffer pMatrix = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);

        {
            p.get(pMatrix);
        }
        //сделали копию матрицы проекции
        Matrix4f p1 = new Matrix4f().set(pMatrix);
        //сделали копию матрицы view
        Matrix4f v = new Matrix4f().set(vMatrix);
        //P*V
        Matrix4f q = p1.mul(v);
        FloatBuffer qF = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
        q.get(qF);


        glUseProgram(rectangleProgram);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(rectangleProgram, "Q"), false, qF);
        glBindVertexArray(vaoRectangle);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, rectangleBuffer);

        float k = 0.3f;
        FloatBuffer fl = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(3 * 8 * Float.BYTES).put(new float[]{
                k, k, 0, k, -k, 0,
                -k, -k, 0, k, -k, 0,
                -k, k, 0, -k, -k, 0,
                -k, k, 0, k, k, 0

        }).rewind();

        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, fl, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        //ОТРИСОВКА
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i += 2)
            drawLine(i);

    }

    void render(MouseInput mouseInput) throws Exception {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // clear the framebuffer
        renderRectangle();
    }
}
```

Вот, что выводится:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну это явно не **0.3x0.3**. В чем причина, подскажите?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, вы рисуете квадрат от -0.3 до +0.3 - значит его размер 0.6x0.6, а не 0.3x0.3.

Во-вторых, и в главных, проверьте, у вас перспективная матрица с углом 45 градусов. Камера у вас расположена на 1.0 по оси Z. Смотрит на 0.0. Квадрат вы рисуете также на 0.0 по оси Z. Размер квадрата будет зависеть от расстояния от камеры. Нарисуйте квадрат на расстоянии 10 (т.е. с координатой Z = -9.0), он станет меньше?

Как сделать, чтобы размер квадрата был 1.0 ? Либо найдите подходящее расстояние у перспективной камеры, либо, что правильнее, перейдите на использование ортогональной камеры (у нее размеры не зависят от расстояния).